# How to convert erlang module (wxImage) const/array to a list in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, wxerlang

I am trying to manipulate a "test.jpg" image in Elixir by using Erlang wxImage library, but I am getting an error. I do not know how to convert the array/const output to a list so I can use it in Elixir.

Also I do not know why there is a clause function error when the syntax seems to be alright?

```
defmodule Imedit2 do
  def readimg(image) do
    {:ok, _file} = File.open("happy737.txt", [:write])
    IO.puts("hi there")
    _output =
      image
      |> File.read!()
      |> :wxImage.getData()
      |> to_charlist()

    # IO.puts(is_list(output))
    # IO.puts(is_tuple(output))
    # IO.binwrite(file, output)
    # File.close(file)
  end
end
```

```
iex(58)> Imedit2.readimg("test.jpg")
hi there
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :wxImage.getData/1

The following arguments were given to :wxImage.getData/1:

    # 1
    <<255, 216, 255, 226, 2, 28, 73, 67, 67, 95, 80, 82, 79, 70, 73, 76, 69, 0, 1,
      1, 0, 0, 2, 12, 108, 99, 109, 115, 2, 16, 0, 0, 109, 110, 116, 114, 82, 71,
      66, 32, 88, 89, 90, 32, 7, 220, 0, 1, 0, 25, ...>>

gen/wxImage.erl:405: :wxImage.getData/1
lib/imedit2.ex:5: Imedit2.readimg/1
```

Comment: You are passing a binary into the function `:wxImage.getData/1`. If you look at the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/wxImage.html#getData-1) for that function, it expects a reference to the image, not the images binary data. I have never used this library before, but it looks like you need to call [`:wxImage.loadFile/{2,3,4}`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/wxImage.html#loadFile-2) in order to load your image from a file. You will probably also need to call the `new/0` function to first get a blank image reference.

Comment: I thought that File.read loads the image and that's why there is an output of numbers as a result of wximage processing the loaded image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a play around with `:wxImage` and I found a couple of problems with your code:

1. You need to call `:wx.new()` to to initialize wx before any of the `:wxImage` functions will work.
2. The argument to`getData/1` should be the image handle, not the binary file data. From the [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/wxImage.html#type-wxImage):

> **wxImage()**
>
> An object reference, The representation is internal and can be changed without notice. It can't be used for comparsion stored on disc or distributed for use on other nodes.

And for [`getData/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/wxImage.html#getData-1):

> **getData(This) -> binary()**
>
> Types
>   This = wxImage()

So you can do it like this:

```elixir
def readimg(image) do
  :wx.new()

  data =
    image
    |> String.to_charlist()
    |> :wxImage.new()
    |> :wxImage.getData()
    |> :binary.bin_to_list()

  :wx.destroy()
  data
end
```

But beware that the `bin_to_list/1` call is slow, and I don't think you need it anyway. You probably want to stop at `:wxImage.new()`, keep the handle in a variable, and use that to call whatever other [`:wxImage` functions](http://erlang.org/doc/man/wxImage.html#exports) you need.